# AS連携とはなんですか？

Tags: database

これはOracle DBのテーブル定義書より、ある項目が「AS連携済フラグ」という論理名で記述されてます。

ASとはなんでしょう？

フラグですので、デフォールトは0で、フラグが立ったら1になります。

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM製のプラットフォーム名である**AS/400**の略ではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど。可能性は高いですね。古いデータは`1`になってるようですので、アーカイブみたいですね。ありがとうございます。